# How can I generate a conditional rolling average?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I want to be able to perform a rolling average on the Data column based on values which are labeled as True in a separate column.  Below is an example data set.

```
                      Data        Condition
2020-01-01 0:00       2.0          False     
2020-01-01 0:01       2.0          False       
2020-01-01 0:02       732.1        True    
2020-01-01 0:03       734.2        True       
2020-01-01 0:04       733.3        True       
2020-01-01 0:05       731.2        True  
2020-01-01 0:06       2.0          False  
2020-01-01 0:07       2.0          False  
...
2020-06-15 23:52      2.0          False       
2020-06-15 23:53      732.1        True    
2020-06-15 23:54      734.2        True       
2020-06-15 23:55      733.3        True       
2020-06-15 23:56      731.2        True 
2020-06-15 23:57      2.0          False      
2020-06-15 23:58      2.0          False       
2020-06-15 23:59      2.0          False
```

My expected output, with a window size of 3, for the data column, would be the following:

[2.0, 2.0, 733.15, 733.2, 732.9, 732.25, 2, 2, ..., 2.0, 733.15, 733.2, 732.9, 732.25, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0].

So essentially, for each row, it would take the average of the row above and below that row, as well as the row in question, but always excluding the numbers when it is false.

Here is some code I found, except for that it is not for the current pandas.

`pandas.rolling_mean(df[df.Condition], window=30)`
I found it here: [Conditional mean by rolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005667/conditional-mean-by-rolling)

Any help or information on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's your expected output for, say `window=3`, in this case?

Comment: My expected output would be [2.0, 2.0, 733.15, 733.2, 732.9, 732.25, 2, 2, ..., 2.0, 733.15, 733.2, 732.9, 732.25, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0] for this case.

Comment: @wes.e  Add your expected output within the question, so it makes it easier to answer, and helps people who find this question via google.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would filter your dataframe to only get the rows that fit your condition, then apply a rolling mean.

```
df['rolling'] = df.loc[df['Condition'] == True]['Data'].rolling(30).mean().fillna(0)
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['Condition'] == True]['Data']` should be `df.loc[df['Condition'] == True, 'Data']`

Comment: When I try this I just get NaN's for the rolling column

Comment: Is there a major difference to doing it that way vs the way in the solution?